# How do i manually focus an element in my php form without clicking it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

My form already returns a value in the first element and loads to the second one, But how do i manually select the first element when i want to start over?  Only a scanner will be connected so it would have to be a keypress or something.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Validate form function -->
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
//  function validateForm()
//  {
//    var x=document.forms["chip_insert"]["order_number"].value;
//    var y=document.forms["chip_insert"]["chip_number"].value;
//    if (x==null || x=="")
//    {
//      alert("Please enter an Order Number.");
//      document.forms["chip_insert"]["order_number"].focus();
//      return false;
//    }
//    if (y==null || y=="")
//    {
//      alert("Please enter a Microchip Number.");
//      document.forms["chip_insert"]["chip_number"].focus();
//      return false;
//    }
//  }

</script> 
-->

<?php
$servername = "server";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "JVSIntranet";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}   
$sql = "INSERT INTO MICROCHIP_TBL (chip_number,order_number)
VALUES 
('$_POST[chip_number]','$_POST[order_number]')";


  IF (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Great Job! You've entered it correctly!";
    } else {
    echo "Error: TRY AGAIN HUMAN!";
  }


    $value = "";
    if( isset( $_POST ["order_number"] )) $value = $_POST ["order_number"];

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getNextElement(field) {
    var form = field.form;
    for ( var e = 0; e < form.elements.length; e++) {
        if (field == form.elements[e]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return form.elements[++e % form.elements.length];
}

function tabOnEnter(field, evt) {
if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else if (evt.stopPropagation) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            evt.returnValue = false;
        }
        getNextElement(field).focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="document.chip_insert.chip_number.focus();">
<center>
<h1>Jeffers HomeAgain Microchip Entry</h1>


<form name="chip_insert"  id="chip_insert" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
Order Number: <input tabindex="1" maxlength="12" type="text" name="order_number"  id="order_number"  value="<?php echo $value; ?>"  required="required"onkeydown="return tabOnEnter(this,event)"  /><br /><br />
Tag Number: <input tabindex="2" maxlength="15" type="text" name="chip_number" id="chip_number" required="required" /><br /><br />
<input tabindex="7" type="submit" />
</center>
</form>

<br />

<!--End body content -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: javascript you can do `element.focus()`

Comment: I've tried a method like that but i'm assuming i didn't do it right.  I was trying to use onKeyPress with elementID.focus.  Any tips?

Comment: So when you click a key you want the focus to go to a specific element your first element or when the page is reloaded you want focus on first element? I'm not quite sure what you are looking for...

Comment: well since loading the page happens after every post i have it to onload focus the second one because i'm returning the first element value, but i would like to keypress to focus the first element when i'm done with it.  It should just highlight it so we can scan over it.

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle

Comment: In HTML5, you have the option of using the autofocus attribute. This would bring focus to an element when the page reloads.

Comment: (http://jsfiddle.net/8y3orxwh/)